# Define size of css classes inside css using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am migrating my small business website to use bootstrap in order to be mobile friendly. I am still getting to know the bootstrap framework and I am not an expert in css either...

My question is a conceptual one. Today with my old website, using html and css, I define in my css both the size (yes, fixed sizes) and styles (colour, etc.) of the divs I use.

On the other hand, in all the examples I've seen of bootstrap, in the css one can only define the style of the divs, while the size is defined in the html when choosing the bootstrap column's size (e.g. col-sm-4). [Note: I am following the approach of having two css, bootstrap's and my custom one.]

The way I see it, I am losing the capacity to define the size of the divs centrally from the css and hence losing maintainability. Also, the site will be harder to develop since the col-sm-* classes are semantically poor. Is this correct? Am I missing something here?

Is there a way to define css classes that reference the bootstrap classes? e.g. To define a .menu css class that can behave as .col-sm-4.

Any suggestion or recommendation is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use any size you like...whether they are bootstrap classes or not. Whether your sizes will fit neatly and arrange nicely with bootstraps is a whole other discussion.

Comment: Well, that was precisely my question.. To get what bootstrap offers but preserving the ability of centralized design. Your answer seems to be that it is not possible..

Comment: Bootstrap is just a framework...you can adapt it (and customise it as you require). Depends really on what you are trying to do...and why you think you would need divs that are specialised (non-bootstrap) sizes.

Comment: You might find this interesting - https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Maybe I did not express myself clearly.. I do want my divs to use bootstraps sizes, my question refers to where I select the bootstrap size to use. The examples I have seen select the size inside the html and not in the css, which I would prefer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. The bootstrap sizes are percentage based around a 12 column grid...you want something 25% wide, use the `-3` column class and so on. All this is customisable though. If you want say 16 columns, you can tweak the custom download options.

Comment: Your concerns are fairly common to people just starting with bootstrap. I think you'll find that it simplifies things for you greatly in the long run. My best advice would be to dig in and learn it, and try not to override anything for layout at first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be easily answered by the documentation.

Comment: I dont feel my question was answered.. but I am losing hope on it..